# BOOT Ubuntu 12.04.3 in UEFI mode

Tags: 12.04, boot, uefi

I have installed ubuntu on my pc (sony vaio pro 13) in uefi mode and the installation completed without any problem. After that when I restart the system does not boot ubuntu so I tried with boot-repair that told me that has fixed the boot successfully, but at the restart again ubuntu does not boot. This is the output of boot-repair http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6196773/ , if someone can hekp me i'll be greatfull because i do not know what to do at the moment!!!
thank you

Claudio

Comment: Please don't edit "[SOLVED]" into your question title. Accepting an answer is already enough to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your installation is not a typical EFI-mode installation. You *do* have an EFI-mode version of GRUB installed on `/dev/sdb5`; however, your `fdisk` output indicates that your disk is partitioned using the MBR system, whereas EFI installations almost always use GPT, and `/dev/sdb5` is marked in the MBR as a Linux partition, not as an EFI System Partition (ESP; the type of partition that holds EFI boot loaders). As 12.04.3 is fairly new, it could be that you've run into a new bug (or set of bugs) in its installer.

I suggest you try the following:

1. Using `fdisk`, change the type code on `/dev/sdb5` (or `/dev/sda5`, if the disks change identities) from 0x83 to 0xEF.
2. Reboot. If it boots to Linux, declare victory and ignore the following steps.
3. Boot the [System Rescue CD.](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) (You could use an Ubuntu live CD/DVD, but that will require you to install `gdisk`, which was awkward from the Ubuntu live CDs/DVDs, the last time I checked.)
4. Launch `gdisk` on `/dev/sdb`. Type `p` to verify you've got the right disk, then type `w` to save the partition table. This should convert the disk from MBR to GPT form. See [this page of the `gdisk` documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) for more on this procedure.
5. Reboot. If it boots to Linux, declare victory and ignore the following steps.
6. Re-run Boot Repair.
7. Reboot. If it boots to Linux, declare victory and ignore the following steps.
8. Download and prepare the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
9. Boot using the rEFInd medium. You should see a rEFInd menu showing three Linux entries, each of which should boot Linux using a different kernel.
10. Try each of the kernels until one boots successfully. If none boot, post back with details.
11. If you can get Linux booted via the external rEFInd medium, install the rEFInd Debian package, remove the external medium, and reboot.
12. If you can boot with rEFInd installed on your hard disk, declare victory. If not, run the [Boot Info Script,](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) post the `RESULTS.txt` file that it creates to a pastebin site, and post back for more help (including the URL to your `RESULTS.txt` file).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the first seven step but after that ubuntu works fine, probably I think that a previous installation of ubuntu not in uefi mode had set up the partition table to mbr and then when I've installed ubuntu in uefi mode it did not change the partition table.

Comment: Your speculation that the problem was caused by a pre-existing MBR partition table is plausible. In fact, your `/dev/sda5` has its boot flag set, and on a GPT disk, libparted uses the "boot flag" as a way to identify the ESP, which is consistent with your explanation. If you're right, though, then this constitutes a bug in the Ubuntu installer, since it should have warned you of the situation or at least set the partition type codes correctly.